# Configuring the default timeout for the SSH agent

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I use `ssh-add` to add my SSH keys to the SSH agent. By default, it adds them indefinitely. There's a command-line option to specify a timeout, but is there a configuration file option which will specify the default timeout?

What I want is to be able to run `ssh-add` without any command-line parameters and have it default to a given amount of time for a timeout (as if I had called `ssh-add -t 1h`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no configuration in `sshd_config` or `ssh_config` to specify the time out for `ssh-agent`. From `openssh` source code, file `ssh-agent.c`:

```
/* removes expired keys and returns number of seconds until the next expiry */  
static time_t                                                                   
reaper(void)                                                                    
{                                                                               
    time_t deadline = 0, now = monotime();                                      
    Identity *id, *nxt;                                                         
    int version;                                                                
    Idtab *tab;                                                                 

    for (version = 1; version < 3; version++) {                                 
        tab = idtab_lookup(version);                                            
        for (id = TAILQ_FIRST(&tab->idlist); id; id = nxt) {                    
            nxt = TAILQ_NEXT(id, next);                                         
            if (id->death == 0)                                                 
                continue;                                                       
            if (now >= id->death) {                                             
                debug("expiring key '%s'", id->comment);                        
                TAILQ_REMOVE(&tab->idlist, id, next);                           
                free_identity(id);                                              
                tab->nentries--;                                                
            } else                                                              
                deadline = (deadline == 0) ? id->death :                        
                    MIN(deadline, id->death);                                   
        }                                                                       
    }                                                                           
    if (deadline == 0 || deadline <= now)                                       
        return 0;                                                               
    else                                                                        
        return (deadline - now);                                                
}
```

And in `process_add_identity` function:

```
process_add_identity(SocketEntry *e, int version)                               
{
.... 
if (lifetime && !death)                                                     
        death = monotime() + lifetime;
....
}
```

`lifetime` is a global variable and only change value when parsing argument:

```
/* Default lifetime in seconds (0 == forever) */                                
static long lifetime = 0;

int                                                                             
main(int ac, char **av)                                                         
{
.... 
    case 't':                                                               
        if ((lifetime = convtime(optarg)) == -1) {                          
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid lifetime\n");                          
            usage();                                                        
        }
....
}
```

If you use Ubuntu, you can set default options for `ssh-agent` in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent`:

```
STARTSSH=
SSHAGENT=/usr/bin/ssh-agent
SSHAGENTARGS="-t 1h"

if has_option use-ssh-agent; then
  if [ -x "$SSHAGENT" ] && [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] \
     && [ -z "$SSH2_AUTH_SOCK" ]; then
    STARTSSH=yes
    if [ -f /usr/bin/ssh-add1 ] && cmp -s $SSHAGENT /usr/bin/ssh-agent2; then
      # use ssh-agent2's ssh-agent1 compatibility mode
      SSHAGENTARGS=-1
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -n "$STARTSSH" ]; then
  STARTUP="$SSHAGENT $SSHAGENTARGS ${TMPDIR:+env TMPDIR=$TMPDIR} $STARTUP"
fi
```

Comment: Funny thing. I tried `SSHAGENTARGS="-s -t 3600"` and it halts with no error, blank screen. But just a curiosity, because your answer is correct and doesn't halt or anything.

Answer (score 20):

If you're calling `ssh-add` on the command line, make a shell alias. Put the following line in your `~/.bashrc` (if using bash) or `~/.zshrc` (if using zsh) or other applicable shell initialization file:

```
alias ssh-add='ssh-add -t 1h'
```

If you want to add a non-expiring key, use `\ssh-add /path/to/key` or `ssh-add -t 0 /path/to/key`.

If `ssh-add` is being called from other program, see if they can be configured to take arguments. Failing that, create a file early on your `$PATH` (`~/bin` is a common choice of directory, make sure it's at the beginning of your `PATH` and create it if it doesn't exist) called `ssh-add` containing

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/ssh-add -t 1h "$@"
```

(Replace `/usr/bin/ssh-add` by the path to the `ssh-add` binary as necessary.)

Comment: A shell alias would probably be the right course of action.

Answer (score 15):

The default timeout is forever. It is however possible to set the *default timeout* for a specific agent through the `-t` option of `ssh-agent`.

from man `ssh-agent`:

```
-t life
        Set a default value for the maximum lifetime of identities added
        to the agent.  The lifetime may be specified in seconds or in a
        time format specified in sshd_config(5).  A lifetime specified
        for an identity with ssh-add(1) overrides this value.  Without
        this option the default maximum lifetime is forever.
```

Comment: Is there a way to configure `ssh-add` so that the default is something other than forever? If I just run `ssh-add` without any parameters, I'd like it to time out after an hour.

Comment: How to launch the `ssh-agent` ?