# Sudo-like utility for ssh, or at least git in particular?

Tags: ssh, git, ssh-agent

I'd like to keep my keys secure, but also not have to enter a passphrase on every single `git` invocation, when I want to run several commands in quick succession. I've researched this, and found that ssh-agent/keychain/etc. go too far convenience-vs-security-wise to my liking. Something like `xyz git pull` would be perfect, where xyz checks if my key is decrypted, and if it isn't - asks for my passphrase, and then after N minutes of not invoking xyz it forgets the decrypted value. Exactly like sudo. Does this exist / can this be achieved through some tricky means?

[There's a similar question about this, but our use cases differ.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191543/is-there-a-technical-reason-why-ssh-agent-lacks-a-sudo-like-inactivity-idle-time)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly what `ssh-agent` does.

> where xyz checks if my key is decrypted, and if it isn't - asks for my passphrase

You don't need any `xyz`. Just start `ssh-agent` at the start of your session (for example in `~/.bashrc`):

```
[ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && eval $(ssh-agent -t 5m)
```

And configure your `ssh` client to add the keys when they are first used by setting

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

in your `~/.ssh/config`.

> and then after N minutes of not invoking xyz it forgets the decrypted value.

This is what the `-t` switch of the `ssh-agent` does. Sets default timeout for added keys (in the example above 5 minutes).

Comment: This is close enough, thanks! Didn't know about `AddKeysToAgent`. However, it's not completely like sudo (though fits my brief description in the question): it's not shell-exclusive (works between several terminals) and it doesn't have a moving window timeout (if I keep invoking it every 10s, then I can keep doing it forever).